# SELinux - Use of SETools' library in a third party program

Tags: java, selinux

I need to write a program in order to analyze SELinux policy. Indeed, existing programs such Apol or Sediffx (from SETools) don't match my needs.
In order to import/use SELinux policy, I intended to use SETools' library (libqpol, libapol, libpoldiff, libsefs). I do have the corresponding .jar but I can't find out how to use them. There is no documentation... And I can't find tutorials or some codes about them...

That's why, I call directly SETools' command-line tools (sesearch, seinfo) from my java program, and then parse the response. In this way I can reconstitute the SELinux policy.

But this seems a bit rough... Do you think there another way to do it? Do you know how to use  SETools' library?